# try / catch en sqlite android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

estoy teniendo un problema con una base de datos sqlite que una de las columnas ya creadas tiene el atributo de unique entonces al insertar duplicado un item este obviamente da un error, lo que quiero es detectar cuando este de error para poder borrar toda la tabla y volver a descargarla sin problemas. Este es mi codigo actual

```
                                //  contenedor.put("cantidad", "0");
                                contenedor.put("id", producto.getString("id"));
                                contenedor.put("foto", "xxxxxxxxxxxx" + producto.getString("foto") + ".jpg");
                                contenedor.put("codigo", producto.getString("codigo"));
                                contenedor.put("descripcion", producto.getString("descripcion").toLowerCase());
                                contenedor.put("descripcion_2", producto.getString("descripcion_2").toLowerCase());
                                contenedor.put("preciomuestra", producto.getString("precio"));
                                contenedor.put("precio", Float.parseFloat(producto.getString("precio")));
                                contenedor.put("categoria", producto.getString("categoria2"));

                                producto_insertado[0] = editorbd.update("productos", contenedor, "id=?", new String [] { producto.getString("id") });
                                producto_duplicado = editorbd.update("productos", contenedor, "descripcion=?", new String [] { producto.getString("descripcion") });
                                if(producto_insertado[0] == 0 && producto_duplicado == 0){
                                    contenedor.put("cantidad", "0");
                                    editorbd.insert("productos", null, contenedor);
                                    contenedor.clear();
                                }else{
                                    contenedor.clear();
                                }
                        }
```

esto esta dentro de un volley que recibe datos actualmente se que no deberia generar problemas si el dato esta duplicado pero quiero evitar futuros errores de cualquier tipo y colocar un try catch para que no crashee la app. Ya probe con el try catch(Exception e) y con (SQLiteConstraintException e) pero nunca entra dentro del catch cuando genera el error. Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> Ya probe con el try catch(Exception e) y con
> (SQLiteConstraintException e) pero nunca entra dentro del catch cuando
> genera el error.

Esto es debido a que **al usar el método `update()` o el método `insert()`, no vas a obtener un error de tipo `SQLiteConstraintException`**, lo que obtendrías sería un valor de -1 en caso de existir un error al insertar o un valor de mayor que 0 indicando los registros modificados:

```
int resultado_update = editorbd.update("productos", contenedor, "id=?", new String [] { producto.getString("id") });

int resultado_insert = editorbd.insert("productos", null, contenedor);
```

**El mejor aproximamiento para este caso es realizar una consulta para saber si existe el registro, en caso de no existir el registro realizar la operación para insertar.**